# Find next greater or equal element using two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search, stack

1. There are 2 arrays of same size, both are sorted in ascending order.
2. If you check the contents of both the arrays position wise, then the element of 2nd array is always greater than the element of 1st array.
3. Pick the smallest number in 1st array(or 1st element of 1st array) then find its next greater or equal element in 2nd array. After finding that element in 2nd array, again find the next greater or equal element in 1st array. Then again find the next greater or equal element in 2nd array.
4. Traverse both the arrays until there is no greater or equal element found.

**Example:**

`arrA[   ] = {134, 160, 187, 195, 200, 208, 232, 249}`

`arrB[   ] = {216, 218, 249, 509, 510, 529, 539, 559}`

**Output:** 134, 216, 232, 249, 249, 509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you `O(n log n)`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arrA[] = { 134, 160, 187, 195, 200, 208, 232, 249 };
        int arrB[] = { 216, 218, 249, 509, 510, 529, 539, 559 };
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        result.add(arrA[0]);
        int max = arrB[0];
        result.add(max);
        int i=1;
        int j=1;
        while(i<arrA.length) {
            if (arrA[i] >= max) {
                max = arrA[i];
                result.add(max);                
                while(arrB[j]<=max) {
                    j++;
                }
                max=arrB[j];
                result.add(max);                
            }else {
                i++;
            }            
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Output::

```
[134, 216, 232, 249, 249, 509]
```

Let me know if it helps